# Change dateformat to dayweek SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So basically I want to return the day of the week according to a date.

Example:

| date format | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 06/10/2023 | Monday |

How can I achieve this within BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
format_date('%A', parse_date('%m/%d/%Y', date_string)) as dayweek
```

with output

[image]